# When upserting a row into SQL via code, how do I avoid duplicate primary key errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am generating the following SQL statement from a JSON object to insert or update a record. Can someone explain why I'm getting this error? My only limitation is that I need to do this in one query- I can't preprocess the data to filter records.

the primary key is combined: ItemID,AwsCoId

Error:

> RequestError: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Items'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Items'. The duplicate key value is (10118, 40454).

JSON object:

```
{ TwoDigitCoID = '40', AwsCoID = '10118', ItemID = '40454' }
```

SQL query

```
insert into [ecomm]..[Items]([TwoDigitCoID],[AwsCoID],[ItemID]) 
    select '40', '10118', '40454' 
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from [ecomm]..[Items] 
                      where [ItemID] = '40454' 
                        and [AwsCoID] = '10118') 

if (@@rowcount = 0) 
    update [ecomm]..[Items] 
    set [TwoDigitCoID] = '40', 
        [AwsCoID] = '10118',
        [ItemID] = '40454' 
    where [ItemID] = '40454' and [AwsCoID] = '10118'
```

Comment: For sanity's sake, what's the actual primary key defined on `Items`? Also, when you say "generate", do you mean you're using a parameterized query, or interpolating the values as a string, as your code seems to imply? The latter has nothing to do with the error as such, but would still be a very bad idea.

Comment: Is this happening in production, and is this your complete statement? Why are you updating columns in your query that are (probably??) a composite key? That makes no sense.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks I added the primary key to the question. it is a composite key of AwsCoId and ItemId

Comment: That doesn't gel with the error you're getting, since that implies the `ItemID` is `10118`, while you're using `40454`. The order is important.

Comment: You could wrap the insert/update in a transaction and specify hint in the subquery `from [ecomm]..[Items] WITH(UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)`.

Comment: Is whatever library you're using to consume the json and run the query treating the two halves as distinct transactions? i.e. it runs the insert, commits, then checks the @@rowcount which is 0 because its a new transaction?  You can test by having the update statement do something else entirely, like create a record of all 9s for instance.

Comment: @hcaelxxam I am unsure about that. Im using the npm package mssql. How would I check to see if its doing this?

Comment: @Rilcon42 sorry, haven't logged in in a few days.  Try changing the update statement to an insert of a record with all 9s.  Then run your script and see if the record you were trying to add shows up and if the record with all 9s shows as well.  If both are present it means that rowcount is not behaving as you expect it to.